# C#. Excel Addin. Can't reposition floating custom task pane

Tags: c#, excel, add-in, excel-addins, customtaskpane

When creating a custom task pane ([_CustomTaskPane MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff558344.aspx)) and setting its **DockPosition** to floating, I want to specify the **Top** and **Left** properties of the window appeared. As Office COM APIs do not provide direct possibility to do this, people advise to alter the values of corresponding properties of CommandBar:

```
var application = (_Application)_nativeTaskPane.Application;
application.CommandBars["Task Pane Title"].Top = top;
application.CommandBars["Task Pane Title"].Left = left;
```

In the code above I assume that

1) _nativeTaskPane is my instance implementing _CustomTaskPane (actually it is Microsoft.Office.Core.CustomTaskPane)

2) _Application is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application

Of course, I'm doing it after setting **Visible = true**. Even subscribed to task pane's **VisibleStateChange** to be more sure. However I'm getting a COMException with the HRESULT E_FAILED.

The thing is I can read these properties (Top & Left) when debugging, however setting them throws exception.

Looks like the issue popped up in the internet at least several times:

1) http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=1&TID=5595

2) [http://aritrasaha.wordpress.com/2009/05/19/programatically-position-office-2007-floating-custom-task-pane/]

3) [http://www.visualstudiodev.com/visual-studio-tools-for-office/need-location-of-custom-task-pane-45822.shtml]

The workaround is using Windows API. However, can anyone explain what can be wrong with using CommandBar-approach? Maybe I can "reconfigure" smth for this Top/Left-setters to work without exceptions.

Comment: Also, the "work-around" link you provided doesn't cater for multiple monitors. On my machine, just moving the window to a given coordinate puts it on the monitor that my office program isn't even on

Answer (score 2):

this is the solution I use in my programs:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Set a custom panes position in the undocked state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="customTaskPane">The custom task pane.</param>
    /// <param name="x">The new X position.</param>
    /// <param name="y">The new Y position.</param>
    private void SetCustomPanePositionWhenFloating(CustomTaskPane customTaskPane, int x, int y)
    {
        var oldDockPosition = customTaskPane.DockPosition;
        var oldVisibleState = customTaskPane.Visible;

        customTaskPane.DockPosition = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionFloating;
        customTaskPane.Visible = true; //The task pane must be visible to set its position

        var window = FindWindowW("MsoCommandBar", customTaskPane.Title); //MLHIDE
        if (window == null) return;

        WinApi.MoveWindow(window, x, y, customTaskPane.Width, customTaskPane.Height, true);

        customTaskPane.Visible = oldVisibleState;
        customTaskPane.DockPosition = oldDockPosition;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowW")]
    public static extern System.IntPtr FindWindowW([System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpClassName, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "MoveWindow")]
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool MoveWindow([System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] System.IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bRepaint);



    /// <summary>
    /// Set a custom panes size in the undocked state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="customTaskPane">The custom task pane.</param>
    /// <param name="width">The new width.</param>
    /// <param name="height">The new height.</param>
    private void SetCustomPaneSizeWhenFloating(CustomTaskPane customTaskPane, int width, int height)
    {
        var oldDockPosition = customTaskPane.DockPosition;

        customTaskPane.DockPosition = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionFloating;
        customTaskPane.Width = width;
        customTaskPane.Height = height;

        customTaskPane.DockPosition = oldDockPosition;
    }
```

Feel free to use it... :-)

Regards, 
Jörg

Answer (score 1):

It should work and there is an interesting comment by MVP Cindy Meister regarding this error here (she tested that it works before answering this forum question) - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2df0e430-4d93-416e-89a0-56f8ad5dc988/seting-position-of-a-floating-custome-task-pane?prof=required

In it, she says that using the wrong variable to get the application object causes the error ie:

```
Globals.MyAddIn.Application -> this will ultimately cause an exception   
Globals.ThisAddin.Application -> this will ultimately work
```

Where we assume that both return the same Application object.

If you think that's bizarre, then you're in good company.

I've added a comment to the question that asks why would the name of the variable used to access the Application object make any difference - surely it's the same Application object being used.

I suspect it's some scary internal, reflection-like limitation imposed by some other internals. But that the innocent developer is not protected from this very odd scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think that once a custom pane is set to `floating` you can't change its top/left properties by definition. what exactly do you want to achieve? do you want to position the pane on specific position? if yes, do it before you set the `visible`property to true

Answer (score 0):

The Commandbar you should be referencing is "Task Pane" which is a standard CommandBar in the CommandBars collection. You got the HRESULT message because the "Task Pane Title" CommandBar was not found in the CommandBars collection.